# js with event Button not wroking

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

**Form.js Code here**

```
import React , {Component} from 'react';
import { Form, Input, Button  } from 'antd';
import axios from 'axios';


class CustomForm extends Component {


handFormSubmit2 = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault()
    const name = event.target.elements.name.value;
    const comment = event.target.elements.comment.value;
    console.log(name , comment)    
    
}
render(){
    return (
        <>
          <Form onSubmit={this.handFormSubmit2}>
            <Form.Item label="Name">
              <Input name='name' placeholder="Enter name here" />
            </Form.Item>
            <Form.Item label="Comment">
              <Input name="comment" placeholder="Comment here" />
            </Form.Item>
            <Form.Item>
                
          <Button type="primary" htmlType="submit">Submit</Button>
            </Form.Item>
          </Form>
        </>
      );
    }
    }
   export default CustomForm;
```

**The problem i am facing is the button is not working even if i remove the event.preventDefault() it stills not submit and refresh the page**

Comment: How can you tell me?

Comment: this is not how you handle forms in react. read the docs about controlled inputs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your are using [antd](https://ant.design/components/form/)
Read the form documentation , you should use their `onFinish` callback instead of `onSubmit`

```
 <Form onFinish={this.handFormSubmit2}>
        <Form.Item label="Name">
          <Input name='name' placeholder="Enter name here" />
        </Form.Item>
        <Form.Item label="Comment">
          <Input name="comment" placeholder="Comment here" />
        </Form.Item>
        <Form.Item>
            
      <Button type="primary" htmlType="submit">Submit</Button>
        </Form.Item>
      </Form>
```

here your full example working with antd

```
import React , {Component} from 'react';
import { Form, Input, Button  } from 'antd';
import axios from 'axios';


class CustomForm extends Component {


handFormSubmit2 = (values) => {
    console.log(values.name , values.comment)    
    
}
render(){
    return (
        <>
          <Form onFinish={this.handFormSubmit2}>
            <Form.Item label="Name" name='name'>
              <Input  placeholder="Enter name here" />
            </Form.Item>
            <Form.Item label="Comment" name="comment">
              <Input  placeholder="Comment here" />
            </Form.Item>
            <Form.Item>
                
          <Button type="primary" htmlType="submit">Submit</Button>
            </Form.Item>
          </Form>
        </>
      );
    }
    }
   export default CustomForm;
```

[working example](https://codesandbox.io/s/serverless-wave-nm7q1?file=/src/App.js)